# inf-sup condition (Finite Element)

Tags: finite-element-method

I have a question about inf-sup condition. In [these](http://www.mathsim.eu/~gkanscha/notes/mixed.pdf) at page 14 is explained the Mixed Formulation in [Mixed Finite Elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_finite_element_method). We can re-write the problem in this way:  let $A:V\to V^\ast, B:V\to Q^\ast, K = \operatorname{Ker} B\subset V, F\in V^\ast,G\in B^\ast $., then
$$
\begin{cases} 
Au + B^Tp = F \\
B u = G 
\end{cases}
$$
In [another book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642365188) it says that the two inf-sup condition for $a$, i.e
$$
\begin{split}
\inf_{v_0\in K} &\sup_{w_0\in K} \dfrac{a(v_0,w_0)}{\|v_0\|\|w_0\|}>\alpha_1 \\
\inf_{w_0\in K} &\sup_{v_0\in K} \dfrac{a(v_0,w_0)}{\|w_0\|\|v_0\|}>\alpha_2
\end{split}
$$

are equivalent to the fact that $A_{KK'}$ is an isomorphism. I try to go more in depth with the details. I can define $A_{KK'}$ given $A$ as a restriction of $A$ to the $K$, i.e
$$
A_{KK'}u_0(v_0) = a(u_0,v_0)
$$
However I am not able to prove these inf-sup conditions from the fact that $A_{KK'}$ is an isomorphism, while I am able to derive it from the coercivity of $A$ in the Kernel. The book suggests to follow the same argument of the first inf-sup condition for $B$: in this case, the inf-sup condition follows from the surjectivity of $B$. I think that the first one follows from the surjectivity of $A_{KK'}$ similarly, while the second one from the surjectivity of the transpose.

Any other helps?

Thank you!

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without access to the book. Please expand the question to contain all necessary information.

Comment: @daw I have tried to go more in depth with the details - hope this is enough!

Comment: the two inf-sup conditions are equal? you need an inf-sup condition for $b$ as well

Comment: The two inf sup condition are slightly different - I have made an error, now fixed. Yes , I know about the one for $b$ , but the proof of that is clear and follows from surjectivity